# Unix find command display file size in gigabyte

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to find files in a certain directory using find command and display the file size as well after finding. Here is what I have come up with so far.

`find /my_search_directory -type f -name "abc*" -printf "%f %k KB\n"`

%k displays the file size in kbs,I want this to be in gbs. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: `%k` isn't even the file size, it's the space taken up by the blocks used for this file, which might be larger than the actual file size. `%s` gives you the (perceived) file size in bytes.

Comment: @Thomas Thankyou for the information,I didnt know that. Is there anyway I can do something with %s to make it display size in gbs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-exec` to run `du` for each file found, passing `-B GiB` to show the size in GiB rather than bytes:

```
find /my_search_directory -type f -name "abc*" -exec du -B GiB {} \;
```

You can also use `-h` instead of `-B GiB` to make `du` choose an appropriate unit; this is probably more useful to you because `-B` rounds upwards. You can also add `--apparent-size` to show the perceived file size instead of the size taken up on disk.

As an extra tip, `sort -h` can be used to process the output of `du -h`:

```
find /my_search_directory -type f -name "abc*" -exec du h {} \; | sort -h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
du -BG filename
```

writes to stdout the size of *filename* in GB.